# Is there any explaination to homeopathies in modern biology sciences?

Tags: human-biology, immune-system

I'd like to know if there is any sort of explaination from rigurous biological arguments which could potentially explain how homeopathies could work?

I'm not talking about placebo effects (psychological) or "water memory" (purely hypothetic), but really about the immune system itself.

Usually, there is only 1, or a really insignifiant amount of toxins after the dillutions for the homeopathies.
But does that mean that there is absolutely no effect on the organism, biologically talking?
Or could there be some immune memory taking place here for example (ik it is usually in adaptative reaction with the lymphocytes, but does it happen with the white cells or other stuff)?

I'm just curious about it :), thanks!

Comment: I searched for duplicates on my internet browser but not on stack exchange itself. Sorry for the duplicate, i'll try to be more aware, and thanks.